# ModelMapper Matching Strategy: Standard with Reference Types

Tags: modelmapper

**Entity Classes:**

```
class User{
    private Name name;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    private Date dob;
    private Address address;

  // No Arguments Constructor , All Arguments Constructor , Setters, Getters and toString
}


class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

   // No Arguments Constructor , All Arguments Constructor , Setters, Getters and toString
}

class Address {
    private String houseNo;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private Integer pincode;

    // No Arguments Constructor , All Arguments Constructor , Setters, Getters and toString
}
```

**DTO:**

```
class UserDTO{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    private Date dob;
    private String houseNo;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private Integer pincode;

   // No Arguments Constructor , All Arguments Constructor , Setters, Getters and toString
 }
```

**Code to convert Entity to DTO:**

```
public class ReferenceTypePropertiesMapper {

@Test
public void shouldPopulateAllSimpleProperties(){
    User user = createUser();
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    UserDTO userDTO = modelMapper.map(user,UserDTO.class);

    System.out.println("Source : "+ user);
    System.out.println("Destination : "+ userDTO);
}

private User createUser(){
    Name name = new Name("Siva", "Prasad");
    Address address = new Address("1-93","ABC","HYD",123456);
    return new User(name, 29, "Siva@gmail.com", new Date(), address);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Source : User(name=Name(firstName=Siva, lastName=Prasad), age=29, email=Siva@gmail.com, dob=Tue Sep 26 14:38:45 IST 2017, address=Address(houseNo=1-93, street=ABC, city=HYD, pincode=123456))

Destination : UserDTO(firstName=Siva, lastName=Prasad, age=29, email=Siva@gmail.com, dob=Tue Sep 26 14:38:45 IST 2017, houseNo=null, street=null, city=null, pincode=null)
```

I am taking 2 reference types **Name** and **Address** in User.java.
While creating object for User , I am passing both Name and Address details as well. When I try to map **User** object to **UserDTO**, **Name** details are getting mapped successfully, but **Address** details are not getting mapped.

Can any body help me in understanding why its happing like that or am I missing any thing?

Answer (score 0):

With [`MatchingStrategies.LOOSE`](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/#matching-strategies) everything works well.

> The Loose matching strategy allows for source properties to be loosely matched to destination properties by requiring that *only* the last destination property in a hierarchy be matched. The following rules apply:
>
> - Tokens can be matched in *any* order
> - The last destination property name must have *all* tokens matched
> - The last source property name must have at least *one* token matched
>
> The loose matching strategy is ideal to use for source and destination object models with property hierarchies that are very dissimilar. **It may result in a higher level of ambiguous matches being detected, but for well-known object models it can be a quick alternative to defining mappings**.

In this way it is necessary to add only one line:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldPopulateAllSimpleProperties() {
        User user = createUser();
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
        UserDTO userDTO = modelMapper.map(user, UserDTO.class);

        System.out.println("Source : " + user);
        System.out.println("Destination : " + userDTO);
    }
```

Output:

```
Source : User{name=Name{firstName='Siva', lastName='Prasad'}, age=29, email='Siva@gmail.com', dob=Wed Oct 18 23:44:25 MSK 2017, address=Address{houseNo='1-93', street='ABC', city='HYD', pincode=123456}}
Destination : UserDTO{firstName='Siva', lastName='Prasad', age=29, email='Siva@gmail.com', dob=Wed Oct 18 23:44:25 MSK 2017, houseNo='1-93', street='ABC', city='HYD', pincode=123456}
```